# Return Set of Available Moves in a Tic-Tac-Toe Board (Python)

Tags: python

Currently building a tic-tac-toe AI in Python. Combing though my functions now, working on finding that sleek "Pythonic" implementation for what I have.

Presently, Im looking at my 'actions' function (returns a set of available moves for player). Any suggestions here?

Some Context:

```
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None

def initial_state():
    """Returns starting state of the board."""
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]
```

Actions Function:

```
def actions(board):
    """Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board."""
    actions = set()

    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            if board[i][j] is None:
                actions.add((i, j))

    return actions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build all actions and then a list comprehension to filter the actions that have already taken place. (trying to be pythonic)

```
ALL_ACTIONS = [(n, m) for n in [0,1,2] for m in [0,1,2]]

def actions(board):
    return set([action in all_actions if board[action[0], action[1]] is None])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy

```
import numpy as np

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None

def initial_state():
    """Returns starting state of the board."""
    return np.array([[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]])

def actions(board):
    return np.argwhere(b == EMPTY).tolist()
```